# asp mvc to spring mvc

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, spring

I have about 4-6 years .NET experience. Primarly using ASP.NET MVC/Nhibernate/Castle Windsor/MSpec/etc in visual studio with Resharper.

I'm starting a new job in a week where we will be using Java with the Eclipse IDE and Spring Framework.

I've read up on the differences between Java and C# and I don't see myself having much trouble adapting (well except java not having LINQ, lambas, etc etc). The architecture style they're using is for the most part the same as I do things in C# as well and I am comfortable with it.

But I installed Eclipse and the Spring tool set and I am completely lost as to where to even begin vs working within Visual Studio. I downloaded a few open source spring apps and I don't even know how to get them to open in Eclipse.

Is there any good sites/tutorials/books anyone could recommend that would get me at least somewhat up to speed with Eclipse/Spring (not Java language books..)? One of my first tasks will be getting the atlassin suite set up as well (primarly Bamboo) which I've never touched before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the community! Those aforementioned books are great ways to learn the Spring framework, but are of substantially less use if you're trying to get started with Java development with Spring, in general, as they can overwhelming. This webinar - http://www.springsource.com/webinar/getting-started-spring-and-springsource-tool-suite - (if you don't want to fill out the form, there's a link that says, "I'd rather not fill in the form. Just take me to the *download page*" in reaaaly tiny fonts below "Download Now!" button. The advantage of that link is that you can download the slides + webinar. If you'd prefer to just watch it online, check out http://www.youtube.com/springsourcedev#p/c/7B74449D5224CC99/0/kSITVsOUvLU ) introduces the SpringSource Tool Suite (a freely downloadable Eclipse derivative) and introduces getting started with simple 80% case type stuff. By the time you're done, you'll have tooling, an idea of what the framework is, and an idea where to get started for a few different approaches. (e.g., "I want to build a web application," or, "I want to data access..") This webinar's an hour, and perhaps then - with a few working examples under your belt in Java - you can tackle those books at your leisure ;-)

Comment: I think learning about core Java technologies won't hurt. When helping people getting started with Spring framework for web based development I recommend some background into JSP, Maven/Ant, Junit. Also it would be good to first work with JDBC and then progress to ORM(JPA, Hibernate). One excellent way to learn spring is by looking at reference examples and reference generated code. In this regard Spring ROO can be a great help(also the spring template projects which you can generate from SpringSource Tool suite)

Comment: well so I spent a couple days going over all the spring stuff it looked pretty cool....then I got the call they are switching to .NET :(

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend these two books:

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Java-Development-Spring-Framework/dp/0764574833](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574833)

[image]

---

[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Spring-Rob-Harrop/dp/1590594614](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594614)

[image]

Both books are from very well known publishers so you can't go wrong with giving them a quick read.

Answer (score 0):

Spring in Action, from manning is the best first book for learning Spring.

You can try Spring Roo as well. It's a command line tool for generating complete web application, with security i18n and so on.

It's so easy to use and you will find the greatest guide for building Spring applications.

There will be a book from manning soon and there's a short introducing book from O'Reilly, available as free download.

Of course, you must visit http://blog.springsource.com/